# break long characters by "-" and identify the unique components by group

Tags: r

Suppose you have a transaction data set with products purchased by customers. You know the total skus (which unique product they buy for each order). But you want to know the unique sku for the lifetime of the user. Say, I buy "apple" for the first time ever today, then apple is a NEW sku. But when I buy "apple" amd "banana" again. Then apple is not a new sku but banana is (if first time purchase).

## data

```
user_id<-c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4)
          order_date<-c("2/9/2016", 
                    "11/19/2015",
                     "12/30/2016",
                     "9/27/2016",
                    "12/10/2016",
                     "11/5/2016",
                     "1/1/2017")  
sku<-c("262-264-280","280-123","510","6251-16990","9227-14572","9227-14572","280")
dt<-data.frame(user_id,order_date,sku)
```

## Output

[image]

update： I typed "user_id" as "order_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible `tidyverse` way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  separate_rows(sku, sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(order_date = as.Date(as.character(order_date), "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(order_id, sku) %>%
  arrange(order_id, order_date) %>%
  mutate(idx = row_number() * (row_number() == 1)) %>%
  group_by(order_id, order_date) %>%
  summarise(sku = paste(sku, collapse = "-"),
            `number of new sku purchase` = sum(idx)) %>%
  group_by(order_id) %>%
  mutate(`total number of sku` = cumsum(`number of new sku purchase`))
```

Answer (score 3):

A *data.table* possibility, using the strings split by `-`, and checking for new unique values in each row via a set `union` and `Reduce(..., accumulate=TRUE)`. The count of new values is then a `diff`erence between each successive row:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, sku := as.character(sku)]
dt[, 
   total := lengths(Reduce(union, strsplit(sku, "\\-"), accumulate=TRUE)),
   by=user_id
  ]
dt[, new := c(total[1], diff(total)), by=user_id]

dt
#   user_id order_date         sku total new
#1:       1   2/9/2016 262-264-280     3   3
#2:       1 11/19/2015     280-123     4   1
#3:       1 12/30/2016         510     5   1
#4:       2  9/27/2016  6251-16990     2   2
#5:       3 12/10/2016  9227-14572     2   2
#6:       4  11/5/2016  9227-14572     2   2
#7:       4   1/1/2017         280     3   1
```

Comment: I was literally posting the same answer. I guess I'll do the scraps and do the base version. I didn't not know about ```lengths```. I used ```sapply(Reduce(...), length)```. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Cole - yeah, `lengths` is a drop-in more efficient replacement for `sapply(x, length)`. I'm not sure how efficient the `Reduce` is really though. There could be a faster solution with splitting to individual rows and looking for `duplicated()` values but I'd have to give it some thought.

Comment: at the end of my post I included my first ```data.table``` approach that uses ```!duplicated()```. I'll also update my post with timings - the base is slightly faster than the data.table version but that's practically fake news for 7 rows with only 4 groups.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option based on `unlist(strsplit(dt$sku,'-'))` the current *sku* then compare it with the previous *skus*

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
  nest(-user_id) %>% 
  mutate(NNSP = map(data, ~map_dbl(1:length(.x$sku), function(y) {
                                   #browser()
                                   ynow <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(.x$sku)[y],'-'))
                                   yprev <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(.x$sku[1:y-1]),'-')))
                                   length(ynow[!ynow %in% yprev])
                                   })),
         TotNNSP = map(NNSP, ~cumsum(.x))) %>%
  unnest()   

# A tibble: 7 x 5
   user_id  NNSP TotNNSP order_date sku        
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>      <fct>      
1        1     3       3 2/9/2016   262-264-280
2        1     1       4 11/19/2015 280-123    
3        1     1       5 12/30/2016 510        
4        2     2       2 9/27/2016  6251-16990 
5        3     2       2 12/10/2016 9227-14572 
6        4     2       2 11/5/2016  9227-14572 
7        4     1       3 1/1/2017   280
```

Using @thelatemail's `Reduce` and `lengths` combination, we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff2 <- function(x, y) y[!y %in% x]

dt %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>% 
   mutate(sku = as.character(sku),
          NNSP = lengths(Reduce(setdiff2, strsplit(sku,'-'), accumulate = TRUE)), 
          Tot_NNSP = cumsum(NNSP))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base solution that is similar to @thelatemail:

```
dt$sku <- as.character(dt$sku)
dt$n_skus <- ave(dt$sku
                 , dt$user_id
                 , FUN = function (sku_f) {
                   sapply(
                     Reduce(union, strsplit(sku_f, '-', fixed = T),  accumulate = T)
                     , length)
                   })

dt$n_skus <- as.integer(dt$n_skus)

dt$n_new <- ave(dt$n_skus
                , dt$user_id
                , FUN = function(n) c(n[1], diff(n)))

dt

  user_id order_date         sku n_skus n_new
1       1   2/9/2016 262-264-280      3     3
2       1 11/19/2015     280-123      4     1
3       1 12/30/2016         510      5     1
4       2  9/27/2016  6251-16990      2     2
5       3 12/10/2016  9227-14572      2     2
6       4  11/5/2016  9227-14572      2     2
7       4   1/1/2017         280      3     1
```

And here's a crazy, inefficient data.table solution that doesn't include the original `sku` field:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, strsplit(as.character(sku), '-'), by = .(user_id, order_date)
    ][, .SD[!duplicated(V1), .(n_new = .N), by = order_date], by = .(user_id)
      ][, n_total := cumsum(n_new), by = .(user_id)][]
```

**Performance** 
@thelatemail's should scale up the best.

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq     max neval
 argonaut_dplyr 10020.601 10247.851 10720.0709 10474.451 10770.751 16021.3   100
 thelatemail_dt  1954.501  2072.101  2385.8019  2303.001  2436.202  5807.0   100
#base is always fastest with 7 rows, it would be outstripped by @thelatemail very quickly
      cole_base   651.501   751.601   834.0299   772.201   794.752  6309.2   100
    cole_bad_dt  7006.400  7355.200  7757.9991  7668.401  7958.651 12708.0   100
    purrr_A_sul 14575.501 14862.552 15566.4809 15033.201 15401.601 33263.3   100
```

Comment: I've just posted an answer and deleted because it's exactly the same to yours. What a coincidence!

Comment: In the middle of posting a data.table solution, thelatemail posted what I was about to. Three people with the same idea is pretty cool, especially when that idea involves ```Reduce```